# SQL works in the database, but get timeout in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timeout

I test with this:

```
$sql_teste = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tbl_membro";
$result_teste = mysql_query($sql_teste);
$ln_teste = mysql_fetch_array($result_teste);

print_r("start " . $ln_teste[0] . " end");
die();
```

And the result was:

> start 90 end

then i tried this one:

```
SELECT profissao_nome, nome, contratacao_tipo_nome, codigo,
cidade_nome, estado_sigla, pais_nome, data,
postagem_descricao, membro_avatar, membro_foto, membro_foto_selecionada
FROM (

SELECT prof.nome as profissao_nome, e.razao_social as nome, ct.nome as contratacao_tipo_nome, v.codigo as codigo,
c.nome as cidade_nome, est.sigla as estado_sigla, p.nome as pais_nome, v.data_ultima_alteracao as data,
v.descricao as postagem_descricao, '' as membro_avatar, '' as membro_foto, '' as membro_foto_selecionada
FROM $tbl_vaga v
JOIN $tbl_empresa e ON v.codigo_empresa = e.codigo
JOIN $tbl_contratacao_tipo ct ON ct.codigo = v.codigo_contratacao_tipo
JOIN $tbl_endereco ende ON ende.codigo = v.codigo_endereco
LEFT JOIN $tbl_cidade c ON c.codigo = ende.codigo_cidade
LEFT JOIN $tbl_estado est ON est.codigo = c.codigo_estado
JOIN $tbl_pais p ON p.codigo = ende.codigo_pais
JOIN $tbl_profissao prof ON prof.codigo = v.codigo_profissao

UNION

SELECT '' as profissao_nome, CONCAT(u.nome,' ',u.sobrenome) as nome, '' as contratacao_tipo_nome, p.codigo as codigo,
'' as cidade_nome, '' as estado_sigla, '' as pais_nome, p.data_postagem as data,
p.descricao as postagem_descricao, m.avatar as membro_avatar, m.foto as membro_foto, m.foto_selecionada as membro_foto_selecionada
FROM $tbl_postagem p
JOIN $tbl_membro m ON m.codigo = p.codigo_membro
JOIN $tbl_usuario u ON u.codigo_membro = m.codigo

) as tab ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

and my result was empty.

When i put:

print_r($sql_teste); and put the code in my database, i got my result just right

> Showing rows 0 - 4 (5 total, Query took 0.0067 sec)

the print_r:

```
    SELECT profissao_nome, nome, contratacao_tipo_nome, codigo,
cidade_nome, estado_sigla, pais_nome, data,
postagem_descricao, membro_avatar, membro_foto, membro_foto_selecionada
FROM (

SELECT prof.nome as profissao_nome, e.razao_social as nome, ct.nome as contratacao_tipo_nome, v.codigo as codigo,
c.nome as cidade_nome, est.sigla as estado_sigla, p.nome as pais_nome, v.data_ultima_alteracao as data,
v.descricao as postagem_descricao, '' as membro_avatar, '' as membro_foto, '' as membro_foto_selecionada
FROM vaga v
JOIN empresa e ON v.codigo_empresa = e.codigo
JOIN contratacao_tipo ct ON ct.codigo = v.codigo_contratacao_tipo
JOIN endereco ende ON ende.codigo = v.codigo_endereco
LEFT JOIN cidade c ON c.codigo = ende.codigo_cidade
LEFT JOIN estado est ON est.codigo = c.codigo_estado
JOIN pais p ON p.codigo = ende.codigo_pais
JOIN profissao prof ON prof.codigo = v.codigo_profissao

UNION

SELECT '' as profissao_nome, CONCAT(u.nome,' ',u.sobrenome) as nome, '' as contratacao_tipo_nome, p.codigo as codigo,
'' as cidade_nome, '' as estado_sigla, '' as pais_nome, p.data_postagem as data,
p.descricao as postagem_descricao, m.avatar as membro_avatar, m.foto as membro_foto, m.foto_selecionada as membro_foto_selecionada
FROM postagem p
JOIN membro m ON m.codigo = p.codigo_membro
JOIN usuario u ON u.codigo_membro = m.codigo

) as tab ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

My guess: timeout. but i don't understand WHY. it took only 0.0067 sec

Comment: Did you try my suggestion - what errors did you get ?

Comment: In my localhost this sql still does not work, but in the server this work. (ok work where it should work, but why does not work in my localhost?)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have a problem but you should be able to see the error message. To see errors on a query do the following :

```
$sql_teste = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tbl_membro";
$result_teste = mysql_query($sql_teste);

// check for error
if (!$result_teste) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n"; // error message
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $sql_teste;
    die($message);
}

$ln_teste = mysql_fetch_array($result_teste);
```

Comment: Sorry for take so long in asnwer you, i was working in other problem. I forgot put the mysql_error() result in my question, i am sorry about that. Here the follow error: `Invalid query: Lost connection to MySQL server during query ` This is why i was thinking that is a timeout problem. I made the same query (without `UNION`, doing 2 query apart from each other, and the result is ok). PS: the query used is the question one. PS2: With your example: `Invalid query: Whole query: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM membro` meaning that the query is OK (i remove the if to show the result blank). Any ideias ?